# code igniter login and signup form in same bootstrap model-content pop c

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is any body tell me how can in create login and signup form inside bootstrap same model-body pop up dialog box  with out creating another model pop up dialog box after create link button fired.

1.Login form in model pop up dialog box

2.After clicking on Create/signup button/link inside login form it will show the signup form in the same bootstrap same model-body pop up overwrite the login form.

Comment: And you have tried what?

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit. You can easily have something like twitter home page for ease of programming. Everything showing up at the same time. Or you need to show a basic HTML's screenshot of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one div for login process and another div as registration process.
Initially set display:none for registration div and if user click on register then hide the first div and display second div.

Demo code

```
 <div class="model-body">
     <div class="login">
      // your code for login
     </div>
     <div class="regitration" style="display:none;">
       // your code for registration
     </div>
 </div>
```